# How to connect a web form to SQL Server in Python?

Tags: sql-server, flask, webforms

I am trying to pass data into database using Flask in python:

My app.py code is below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
import pyodbc
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from urllib import parse

app = Flask(__name__)

params = parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=;")
engine = SQLAlchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
print(engine)    

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        AddressID = request.form['AddressID']
        EntityID = request.form['LegalEntityID']
        connection = engine.connect()
        connection.execute("insert into [Repp_Address](AddressId,LegalEntityID) VALUES ('%s','%s')", 
        AddressID,EntityID))
        connection.close()
        return 'success'
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I am getting the following error:

> engine = SQLAlchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" %
>   params) TypeError: create_engine() missing 2 required positional
>   arguments: 'sa_url' and 'engine_opts'

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you still need to create an instance of your SQLAlchemy class. (Right now SQLAlchemy knows nothing about your app and has no configuration)

you can do this by after creating the app.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

next problem is that the create_engine method still expects 2 positional arguments, as shown in your traceback.

To get the engine options add the following below "db = ":

```
engine_options = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS']
```

now you should be able to create the engine as follows:

```
url = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params
engine = db.create_engine(url, engine_options)
```

Maybe you are used to vanila SQLAlchemy, but the Flask extension works a little bit differently. Hope this helps.